# Make a custom of periodic tasks in django celery

Tags: python, django

i read about celery about periodic tasks use :

```
# Import for custom tasks
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute="*/2"))
  def print_mail():
    print("Send Mail to A Specific Time")
```

i want to know if i can change the time in minute not set already but from an input of the form and the task will run periodic by the time of form input , can celery do that and how ??? , tks you !